# angular2 Observable Property 'debouceTime' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-forms

I use **"angular2 webpack"** and **"angular2/form,Observable"** , but met an error ,need help ..

There is a custom form validator --

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

emailShouldBeUnique(control:FormControl) {
    return new Observable((obs:any)=> {
      control.valueChanges
        .debouceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMap(term=>return !this.userQuery.emailExist(term))
        .subscribe(res=> {
            if (!res) {obs.next(null)}
            else {obs.next({'emailExist': true}); }; }
        )});}
```

I could find the file  **"/projection_direction/node_modules/rxjs/operator/debounceTime.js"**

why is there such the error--

> Property 'debouceTime' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Be sure you've initiated that in main.ts *(where the app is bootstraped)*

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
...
```

or all at once

```
import "rxjs/Rx";
```

EXTEND

there is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gk8apNhLx5blpBcDHdq2?p=preview)

```
//our root app component
import {Component, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'
import {Observable} from  "rxjs/Rx";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

        <div>debounced message: {{message}}</div>
    </div>
  `, 
  directives: []
})
export class App {

  protected message: string;
  protected emitter = new EventEmitter<string>();
  public obs: Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'

    this.obs = this.emitter
      .map(x => x)
      .debounceTime(1200)
      ;

    this.obs.subscribe(msg => this.message = msg);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.emitter.emit("hello after debounce");
  }
}
```

and that is working when in main.ts we have:

```
//main entry point
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {App} from './app';

import "rxjs/Rx"; 

bootstrap(App, [])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gk8apNhLx5blpBcDHdq2?p=preview)

Comment: i add `import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime" now ; ` in the main.ts,,but the error is still...

Comment: I created a plunker for you, extended the answer .. hope it should help

Comment: @RadimKöhler I think the Plunker is erroring. Personally I see TS errors 
`Argument of type '(term: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Answer (score 34):

For everyone coming here after rxjs 6:

You now need to use a `pipe()`:

What was

```
myObservable$
    .debounceTime(500)
    .subscribe(val => {
    // debounced stuff
})
```

needs now to be:

```
myObservable$
    .pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe(val => {
    // debounced stuff
})
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo here. It's debounceTime, not debouceTime :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar error while working with angular v5.2.6 and rxjs v5.5.6 on an angular-cli 1.6.8 generated project. I originally had:

```
import { debounceTime, map } from 'rxjs/operators;
```

since I was subscribing for a control valueChanges event and I kept getting the error until I put

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

For me, the answer was using the pipe:

```
.pipe(debounceTime(500))
```

Plus changing the import from:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
```

To:

```
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
```

And yes, I was following a tutorial, so hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

Aug 2019

An example:

Imports:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators";
```

In component class:

```
resizeEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
onResize(event: any) {
  this.resizeEvent.next(event);
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("in ngOnInit");

  this.resizeEvent
    .pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe(this.actualResizeHandler);
}

actualResizeHandler(event: any) {
  //   event.target.innerWidth;
  console.log("in actualResizeHandler");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem recently, and solved after I did:

```js
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And also added pipe as it is required I think for Angular 5+

```js
something.pipe(debounceTime(100)).subscribe(something...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have to use **debounceTime()** with multiple RxJS operators, I would suggest use **.pipe()** operator

```
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

 functionName(value: Observable<string>) {
    return .pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(location => this.secondFunc(value))
    )
  }
```