# TSLint annoying message

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, tslint

On my angular's component i'm using two methods from RxJs, `debounceTime()` and `distinctUntilChanged()`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form4th',
  templateUrl: './form4th.component.html',
})
export class Form4thComponent implements OnInit {
  searchField: FormControl;
  searches: string[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchField = new FormControl();
    this.searchField
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(term => {
          this.searches.push(term);
        });
  }
}
```

**App works fine**, **no error or even no warning message** when doing (build) i.e. `ng serve`, and running the app on browser **works as expected** and no error message or warning too on browser console.

**However**, I have this weird TSLint message on my vscode saying:

`[ts] Property 'debounceTime' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.`

it's kind of annoying, since i kinda worry something doesn't work under the hood that i''m not aware of.

What am i missing here?
Thank You.

Comment: It is not a `TSLint` but a `TypeScript` message.

Comment: alright then, what's the problem here?

Comment: Snippests are for **runnable** examples. For just code blocks, use code blocks.

Comment: @xcode [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38005838/7579291) might be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 Observable Property 'debouceTime' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005762/angular2-observable-property-deboucetime-does-not-exist-on-type-observablean)

Comment: I'm prefer to use `import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";` rather than `import "rxjs/Rx";` (my tslint.json also block the import of whole rxjs, i prefer that) but after putting `import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";` on `main.ts` the message still appear, why?

Comment: it turns out i need to restart vscode after putting those import at `main.ts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in some comments, it's not a TSLINT error, it's a Typescript error.

The thing here, you're patching the prototype of `Observable` when you do that:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';`

Instead of doing that, you might just want to take advantage of a new feature called `lettable operators` since rxjs v5.5. It let you use a new `.pipe` operator which takes functions as argument (rxjs operators or your own).

So instead of your code, try the following one:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

// notice this import will not patch `Observable` prototype
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form4th',
  templateUrl: './form4th.component.html',
})
export class Form4thComponent implements OnInit {
  searchField: FormControl;
  searches: string[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchField = new FormControl();

    this.searchField
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(term => {
        this.searches.push(term);
      });
  }
}
```

By not patching the prototype of `Observable` it'll help your bundler to do tree shaking (if available) but I'm sure it'll be easier for Typescript to make the necessary checks as the functions will have to be imported in the same file. (that said, I've been using the old fashion method for a while and VSC was working as expected).

Comment: i tried your alternative, but still vscode still give me warning `[ts] Property 'debounceTime' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.` even though the compile is successful and app works fine. It's kind of annoying.

Comment: import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators'; //does it miss the "from"?