# Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'Observable<unknown>'.ts (2339)

Tags: angular

After upgrading Angular, original code below complaints

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, "keyup")
      .debounceTime(150)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(...
```

Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005762/angular2-observable-property-deboucetime-does-not-exist-on-type-observablean), I changed import to

```
import { Observable, of, BehaviorSubject, merge, fromEvent} from "rxjs";
import { map, startWith, distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators";
```

`Observable.fromEvent` to `fromEvent`. Now goes down to `debounceTime`, and `distinctUntileChanged()` will be next.

How to convert the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify like this.

```
  fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, "keyup").pipe(
    debounceTime(150),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  ).subscribe(...
```